# Filter tables and views created by the user

Tags: sql, oracle11g

[image: This is how i get- image]

When I execute the command:

```
select * from tab;
```

As soon as I enter the database, I get a lot of in-built tables, as well as tables and views created by me.

How do I separate them? How do I view only the tables and views created by me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query for tables owned by you :

```
SELECT table_name
  FROM user_tables
```

For Views :

```
select view_name from user_views
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT owner, table_name FROM dba_tables where owner = 'XXXX';

where XXXX is a schema name.

Comment: `dba_tables` is not accessible for a regular user

Comment: then SELECT * FROM user_tables;